# The partial derivative of the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

Is there anyone who could write more steps between the function $c$ and its partial derivation with respect to $K$. I tried to derive it with use of integration by parts and with reversing the limits of integration, but I didn't come to the same conclusion as in this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your equations, formulae etc. instead of attaching an image. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard Leibniz formula for differentiating a function like
$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(x,t)\,dt.$$
The formula is
$$F'(x) = f(x,x) + \int_a^x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\,dt.$$
The first term comes from the fundamental theorem of calculus, and the second term comes from "differentiation under the integral sign." Since $f(x,t)=(t-x)g(t)$, note that $f(x,x)=(x-x)g(x) = 0$ (there's a little bit of sloppiness in their first term, since they didn't evaluate $g$ at $K$). The negative sign appears because $\int_x^a = -\int_a^x$, just as with usual single-variable applications of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Thank you Ted, I understand that now.